# How to create an MVC 5 project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When I select ASP.NET Web Application template my template chooser screen looks like this:
[image]

There's no MVC template for ASP.NET 4.6. Same for 4.5 Framework versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you choose the Web Application under the ASP.NET 5 Preview Templates you will have a project that uses ASP.NET MVC and can be used to build Web Applications or Web API RESTFul services.

I do have the Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, this is what I see:
[image]

after you click this OK button, you will create a MVC 6 project in this VS2015

Did you have the "Microsoft Web Developer Tool" checked when you started the installation?

Comment: You were right, Microsoft Web Developer option of the Studio hasn't been installed :)

Comment: Why was this accepted as the answer, this is for MVC 6 and the question is for MVC 5?

Comment: It's very obvious why I accepted this, it was the first answer that mentioned "Microsoft Web Developer Tools" that I haven't had installed in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

to see the MVC template, download ans install the Microsoft Web Developer Tools.

Then, below the *aspnet 4.6 templates* will be your template **MVC 5**

To use MVC 6 (Now it is called MVC Core 1.0) choose Web Application under the Asp.Net 5 Template, and then MVC.

Att,

Answer (score 1):

As you had asked about **MVC 5**, and you don't have it in your template[as in screen shot] and not asking about **asp.net 5**,

You can download **asp.net and web tool** [Here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c94a02e9-f2e9-4bad-a952-a63a967e3935) [VS Extension].

or you can directly add **Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3** [Here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.mvc/) [NuGet Package].

Here's prerelease version of [**MVC 6.0.0 rc1**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/6.0.0-rc1-final) [NuGet Package].

Alternate Link
**Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015 (RC) – Visual Studio 2015** : [Microsoft Website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49959)

Answer (score 0):

There is a web application.. curretnly it is still in beta,but it provides good backend architecture and very fast download of functional MVC template

http://asptemplatestack.com/Templates/GetAll

Comment: You should use the comments for this kind of suggestions. Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)