# Which template should be select for creating an ASP.NET MVC5 project in VS2015?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have seen [How to create an MVC 5 project in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548272/how-to-create-an-mvc-5-project-in-visual-studio-2015) before asking this question, but it was asked one year before and I need an actual answer of my question. Which template should I select for creating an MVC5 project? According to the explanations of ASP.NET5 Web Application, it seems to use MVC template and have more features. But if so, why MVC checkbox is not selected? I am confused with this selections.

**ASP.NET 4.5.2 Template**

[image: ASP.NET 4.5.2 Template]

**ASP.NET 5 Template**

[image: ASP.NET 5 Template]

Comment: @StephenMuecke Do you have any idea regarding to this issue? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Does anybody else has never thought this issue ever before?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at old (preview) templates. ASP.NET 5 in fact no longer exists, it was re-introduced as ASP.NET Core 1.0.
Most likely you will want to use the 4.5.x template. Or you can read up on ASP.NET Core to see if that suits your needs, because it is still an early product.

More info:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply, I read that. But as you mentioned, it is an early stage and I do not want to switch to that. On the other hand, I am thinking about to learn and use AngularJS but have no idea which platform (ASP.NET MVC, Core, or Java) to use with AngularJS? Do you have any idea?

Comment: AngularJS is a browser technology that can be combined with many back-end or server technologies, including MVC. For example see this: https://www.gurustop.net/blog/2016/07/05/how-to-use-angular2-with-aspnet-4-5-aspnetmvc-5/

Comment: Which technology of Microsoft do you suggest to use AngularJS 2 with?